# Couchbase not setting new attributes to all documents

Tags: couchbase

I have a bucket of 50k records in production. I am supposed to add a new attribute for all the documents. For that, I am executing below queries through web console query workbench.

`select count(*) from my-bucket where orderType is missing;` --50k records

`update my-bucket set orderType = “MY_ORDER” where orderType is missing;` –- mutation = 49950

> Issue 1: Couchbase is not selecting all my documents for mutations.
>
> Issue 2: Post update, when i again try to look for the number of
>   documents for which the new attribute is missing, the count keeps on
>   increasing.

`select count( * ) from my-bucket where orderType is missing;` --100 records

`select count( * ) from my-bucket where orderType is missing;` --200 records

`select count( * ) from my-bucket where orderType is missing;` --350 records

Can someone please explain the reasons as well as the solution to this problem. We are running these queries in a live production environment.

**Couchbase server version: Community edition 5.1**

Comment: Dummy question here, isn't the documents increasing because you haven't deployed a new version of your application in production with this new attribute?

Comment: No. This whole time total count of bucket remained same.

Comment: Also, this issue got resolved on its own. Only possible explanation we have is that some job was running in background and this issue came due to concurrent modification.

Comment: In Community Edition, the N1QL engine is single-threaded, so it may take some time for that UPDATE statement to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try select count(meta().id) from my_bucket where orderType is missing. Apparently count(*) doesn’t work correctly with where clause in couchbase

Comment: We have been able to execute these queries using count (*) on one of the test servers. The issue is coming only on prod servers. Further, we have tried updating the bucket without any where clause. And then tried select count(meta().id) and the count is keep on increasing as earlier.